# angular2 TypeError: self._el_11 is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror, keyup

i want to add event listener to input ,here is my code

```
<input ref-search (keyup)="search(search.value)">
```

and search method is

```
search(condition: string){
    console.log(condition);
}
```

then when i input something,the browser console log is

```
TypeError: self._el_11 is not a function
at AppView._View_YwCoffeeListComponent0._handle_click_11_0 (YwCoffeeListComponent.ngfactory.js:217)
at platform-browser.umd.js:1854
at platform-browser.umd.js:1967
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:192)
at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (core.umd.js:8772)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:191)
at Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:99)
at NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded (core.umd.js:8805)
at NgZone.runGuarded (core.umd.js:9038)
at HTMLInputElement.i (platform-browser.umd.js:1967)
```

and YwCoffeeListComponent.ngfactory.js:217 code is

```
_View_YwCoffeeListComponent0.prototype._handle_click_11_0 = function($event) {var self = this;self.markPathToRootAsCheckOnce();var pd_0 = (self._el_11(self._el_11.value) !== false);return (true && pd_0);};
```

Comment: Can i see your javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you define template reference variable with the same name as your method.

So change it with:

```
<input ref-searchInput (keyup)="search(searchInput.value)">
```

Comment: Omg, you saved me hours of debugging. Thank's !